# IPython Kernel Died when Construct Qt Class

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, ipython, pyside

Has anyone ever experienced this before? Or it just me?

I tried to construct b class and inherit QWidget Class from PySide Qt. Everytime i tried, the kernel died and restarting. Do you have any idea what's wrong with my code? Or it was another reason for that?

Here's the code I wrote:

```
from PySide.QtCore import *

from PySide.QtGui import *

class b(QWidget):
     ...:     def __init__(self, parent=None):
     ...:         super(b, self).__init__(parent)
     ...:         self.var1 = ''
     ...:     def koplak(self):
     ...:         print self.var1

koplak2 = b()

Kernel died, restarting
```

I'm running Python 2.7.5 with Anaconda distribution 64bit

Comment: Can you show the backtrace?

Comment: @LaszloPapp i'm sorry, i'm not an expert. would you show me the way to do backtrace?

Comment: You will need to create a `QApplication` before instantiating a `QWidget`. Does it work if you do so?

Comment: yes, you found it @LaszloPapp. it seems legit, creating QApplication class before instantiating QWidget really solve the problem